# Long running in-process Publish/Subscribe class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, multithreading, observer-pattern

I have a Pub/Sub class that will call `Notify()` when published and that `Notify()` could take around 10 seconds, so I need to make sure that this does not block the UI.

```
public static class NotificationService
{
    private static Dictionary<string, INotification> Observers { get; }

    static NotificationService()
    {
        Observers = new Dictionary<string, INotification>();
    }

    public static void Publish(string title, string requester)
    {
        foreach (var observer in Observers)
        {
            var notification = observer.Value;

            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                notification.Notify(title, requester);
            }).Start();

        }
    }

    public static void Subscribe(INotification notification)
    {
        INotification notificationValue;
        if (Observers.TryGetValue(notification.NotificationName, out notificationValue))
        {
            // Observer already exists
            return;
        }

        Observers[notification.NotificationName] = notification;
    }

    public static void UnSubscribe(INotification notification)
    {
        INotification notificationValue;
        if (!Observers.TryGetValue(notification.NotificationName, out notificationValue))
        {
            // Observer doesn't exists
            return;
        }
        Observers.Remove(notification.NotificationName);
    }
}
```

**INotification**

```
public interface INotification
{
    string NotificationName { get; }

    bool Notify(string title, string requester);
}
```

**Example implementation of INotification**

```
public class EmailMessageNotification : INotification
{
    public EmailMessageNotification(EmailNotificationSettingsService settings)
    {
        EmailNotificationSettings = settings;
    }

    private EmailNotificationSettingsService EmailNotificationSettings { get; }
    public string NotificationName => "EmailMessageNotification";
    public bool Notify(string title, string requester)
    {
        var configuration = GetConfiguration();
        if (!ValidateConfiguration(configuration))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var message = new MailMessage
        {
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            To = { new MailAddress(configuration.RecipientEmail) },
            Body = $"User {requester} has requested {title}!",
            From = new MailAddress(configuration.EmailUsername),
            Subject = $"New Request for {title}!"
        };

        try
        {
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient(configuration.EmailHost, configuration.EmailPort))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configuration.EmailUsername, configuration.EmailPassword);
                smtp.EnableSsl = configuration.Ssl;
                smtp.Send(message);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SmtpException smtp)
        {
            Log.Fatal(smtp);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Fatal(e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private EmailNotificationSettings GetConfiguration()
    {
        // Gets and Returns Config
    }

    private bool ValidateConfiguration(EmailNotificationSettings settings)
    {
        // Do some validation
    }
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems that you have a global static logger methods. It is not a good practice, as you're loosing the possibility to tune logging levels for different areas of your application (e.g. setting log level for `EmailMessageNotification` to `DEBUG` while keeping `INFO` level everywhere else. I recommend to follow the logging patterns suggested for your logging framework (see [Creating loggers for NLog](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#creating-loggers) for example).
2. The code is not thread-safe, so you may get issues if your application publishes, subscribes or unsubscribes in different threads. Use either locking around `Observers` collection or ‎`ConcurrentDictionary`.
3. `Fatal` logging level should be used only when the application encounters a critical error after which it usually cannot continue to run. In your case I would suggest to use `Error` log level when email cannot be sent.
4. `NotificationService` is static, which means that you will have a strong dependencies in your code on this class. I suggest to introduce IoC framework (check out [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) or [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/)).
5. The response of `INotification.Notify(string, string)` is not used, so it can be `void`.
6. Your current code requires spinning up threads per each observer per each notification. I suggest to switch to asynchronous processing model, changing the return type of `INotification.Notify(string, string)` to `Task`.
7. Most likely you would want to wrap the notification of each listener in `try..catch` to avoid side effects when buggy `INotification` subscribes to your service

As a result:

**`INotification`**:

```
public interface INotification
{
    string NotificationName { get; }

    Task NotifyAsync(string title, string requester);
}
```

**`EmailMessageNotification`**:

```
public class EmailMessageNotification : INotification
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public EmailMessageNotification(EmailNotificationSettingsService settings)
    {
        EmailNotificationSettings = settings;
    }

    private EmailNotificationSettingsService EmailNotificationSettings { get; }

    public string NotificationName => "EmailMessageNotification";

    public async Task NotifyAsync(string title, string requester)
    {
        var configuration = GetConfiguration();
        if (!ValidateConfiguration(configuration))
        {
            return;
        }

        var message = new MailMessage
        {
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            To = { new MailAddress(configuration.RecipientEmail) },
            Body = $"User {requester} has requested {title}!",
            From = new MailAddress(configuration.EmailUsername),
            Subject = $"New Request for {title}!"
        };

        try
        {
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient(configuration.EmailHost, configuration.EmailPort))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configuration.EmailUsername, configuration.EmailPassword);
                smtp.EnableSsl = configuration.Ssl;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (SmtpException smtp)
        {
            logger.Error(smtp);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e);
        }
    }

    private EmailNotificationSettings GetConfiguration()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private bool ValidateConfiguration(EmailNotificationSettings settings)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**`NotificationService`**:

```
public interface INotificationService
{
    void Publish(string title, string requester);
    void Subscribe(INotification notification);
    void UnSubscribe(INotification notification);
}

public class NotificationService : INotificationService
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, INotification> Observers { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, INotification>();

    private static async Task NotifyAsync(INotification notification, string title, string requester)
    {
        try
        {
            await notification.NotifyAsync(title, requester).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, $"Notification '{notification.NotificationName}' failed with exception");
        }
    }

    public async void Publish(string title, string requester)
    {
        IEnumerable<Task> notificationTasks = Observers.Values.Select(notification => NotifyAsync(notification, title, requester));

        await Task.WhenAll(notificationTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void Subscribe(INotification notification)
    {
        Observers.TryAdd(notification.NotificationName, notification);
    }

    public void UnSubscribe(INotification notification)
    {
        Observers.TryRemove(notification.NotificationName, out notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the `NotificationService` being static, this is because I am subscribing observers from different places in the Application. So If I wanted to Pusblish to all observers I would need to `new()` and then resubscribe all observers?
Regarding the loggers, Looks like I removed them from the original question (I trimmed some usless stuff out). They are private static per class and not something global.

Comment: IoC framework will allow you to use `NotificationService` as a dependency (receive the instance of `INotificationService` in the constructor) rather than instantiate it yourselves. I would recommend you to look deeper into Dependency Injection pattern

Comment: I am currently using an IOC container with constructor injection, so get the instance of the service (Like a singleton) via DI?

Comment: yes, wherever you need an instance of `INotificationService`- just inject it in constructor. At the registration time you should specify that only one instance of the `NotificationService` should be created (`SingleInstance` in Autofac, `.Singleton()` in StructureMap)